# appendChild does not work

Tags: javascript, appendchild

First of all: I'm not much schooled with javascript. So have a problem with the appendChild method. That's my code:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('innerWrap');
var post = document.createElement('input');
post.style.position = "absolute";
post.style.top = "100px";
document.wrapper.appendChild(post);
```

Why doesn't it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try wrapper.appendChild(post); ?

Answer (score 6):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an NodeList, not a Node

So you could try `var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('innerWrap')[0];`

Comment: Hence the plural in `getElementsByClassName`. :)

Comment: I have replaced getElementsByClassName with getElementById to test it with another object (just to trail) but I still get the error "uncaught typeerror cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined".

Comment: What does `getElementById` return? Have you tried a `console.log()` on it? It could be that the JavaScript is executed before the DOM is ready

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a `NodeList`, which is array-like (with a `length` property and numeric properties) but not an actual `Array`.

Comment: Now it works perfectly! I use this code:

    `var post = document.createElement('input');`
    `post.style.position = "absolute";'`
    `post.style.top = "100px";`
    `document.getElementsByClassName('innerWrap')[0].appendChild(post);`

Thanks to @paulslater19 and  @TimDown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
wrapper.appendChild(post);
```

instead of

```
document.wrapper.appendChild(post);
```

?

Comment: That would make no difference, as `wrapper` is a variable on the document object anyhow.

Comment: It's a variable of window object, not document.